# 3-phase electricity availability in USA

Tags: power-engineering

I want to ask about availability of 3-phase electricity in USA.

I live in Europe, in small town (population: 3000). We have 3-phase electricity available everywhere, even in small villages near my town.

How does it look like in USA?

Is there 3-phase grid available in villages and small towns?

Comment: Does this has something to do with electronic design?!!

Comment: No, but site logo says "Electrical engineering", so I asked about this.

Comment: my mistake. I thought this site was meant for electronic design questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Site help says: "This site is for electronics **and electrical** engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts." http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Kamil You can ask some of your questions in chatroom or other electronic forums, not here. specially when it's possible that you get down-vote.

Comment: Electronic design *is* concerned with electric power distribution and availability, so in that aspect it is on-topic. However, the question is asking about availability and price for a specific geography (the US), and in that sense, it is *off-topic* because it will vary within areas of the US (too broad) and is subject to change as both prices and availability change. Therefore it is more like a shopping question (Where can I buy *x*?), which is off-topic.

Comment: OK. I changed my question a bit.

Comment: If it's not acceptable here, this might modifiable to be on topic at diy.se.  I'm not sure though, so please confirm with their moderators before attempting to move it.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask this on travel.SE: [travel.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three phase power is used everywhere in North America (Canada and the US), and is brought down **major** streets, but residences and side streets only get a single phase. Just because it is brought down a major residential street does not mean it is brought into homes on that street, it isn't usually. A single phase distribution transformer steps down a single phase to the center-tapped 240VAC/60Hz that is commonly used in residences.

It's very unusual to see three phase in a home (perhaps in a monster home that is more like a hotel in scale), but in commercial and industrial locations, it is *de rigueur*.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use single-phase power and a capacitor box to start a three-phase motor which is mechanically unloaded.  Once such a three-phase motor has started and has established within it a properly rotating field, single-phase power will suffice to keep the magnetic field spinning provided it is not loaded too heavily.  The rotating magnetic field within the three-phase motor will then generate three-phase current which may be sufficient to start a larger motor.  I know someone who lives in the country two has two three-phase pieces of industrial equipment along with a capacitor box.  The box is only powerful enough to start the smaller machine, and only when it's mechanically unloaded; the smaller machine generates enough three-phase power to start the larger machine when both are electrically unloaded.  Once the larger machine is started, it will run just fine provided it is not mechanically loaded too heavily.  Mechanically loading the larger machine too heavily will stall both motors (I think popping a breaker before the smaller motor is damaged).

Answer (score 0):

The short version is "it depends"; if 3-phase is already on the poles running past your house it's relatively cheap to get connected.  If the nearest customer is several miles away (quite possible in residential areas with older wiring) then the power company is likely to refuse unless you pay to install several miles of new wire.

In areas that use pole top transformers you generally can potentially answer the 'is it available' question by looking to see if they're installed in triples or individually; the former configuration normally means 3phase is being ran through neighborhood the later that it is not.